# Call a method based on the value of a property

Tags: php, class, methods, properties

I have a large list of methods that I call based on the value of a property. I was wondering if there is a more correct method todo what I am doing?

My code now:

```
if ($qvalue->fid == 1) { $this->Archive1(); }
if ($qvalue->fid == 2) { $this->Archive2(); }
if ($qvalue->fid == 3) { $this->Archive3(); }
if ($qvalue->fid == 4) { $this->Archive4(); }
if ($qvalue->fid == 5) { $this->Archive5(); }
if ($qvalue->fid == 6) { $this->Archive6(); }
if ($qvalue->fid == 7) { $this->Archive7(); }
if ($qvalue->fid == 8) { $this->Archive8(); }
if ($qvalue->fid == 9) { $this->Archive9(); }
if ($qvalue->fid == 10) { $this->Archive10(); }
...
```

Can I do something like this:

```
$this->Archive($qvalue->fid)();
```

I know this wont work, I just am not sure if something better is possible. Not even sure what to search to see other posts similar.

Comment: It depends on what is in `Archive9(), Archive10()` and so on

Comment: I am just wondering if there is a better way to call/run the Archive9() method. It shouldn't matter what is in it.

Comment: What matters is, having a bunch of functions that do the same thing (just with *presumably* different data) is a broken design.  It doesn't scale worth a damn.  If the difference is the data, then they should be one method, for the same reason that `$item1`, `$item2`, `$item3`... should actually be an array.  (If you don't like having to pass the params to each function, then you could store them in an array of associative arrays, indexed by the value of `$qvalue->fid`.)  If the functionality is different, that's another matter.  (But it also means that your *names* are broken.)

Comment: The archive methods are spread out across a couple of extended classes, that is why I am using methods, so the parent class can call methods inside the extended class. The extended class can differ from install to install of this script.

Comment: PHP is extremely flexible with things like that.  If you have an array like `$method = [$obj, 'doStuff'];`, that array is a *callable*, and `$method()` does the same thing as `$obj->doStuff()`.  Likewise, for `$f = ['ClassName', 'doStaticStuff'];`,  `$f()` works like `ClassName::doStaticStuff()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$method = 'Archive' . $qvalue->fid;
if (method_exists($this, $method))
{
    $this->$method();
}
```

Comment: I just ran a few tests and this works great. Thank you!